# Supersymmetric variation of $F$ term using super Jacobi identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, superalgebra

Basically, i am solving problems in [note](http://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/lect3.pdf)  with a slightly different notation.

\begin{align}
[Q_\alpha F] = -i \lambda_\alpha (x), \quad [ \bar{Q}_{\dot{\alpha}},F] = -i \bar{\chi}_{\dot{\alpha}}
\end{align}

I obtain $\lambda_\alpha$ is vanishing. But i am not sure for obtaining $\chi$ as a total derivative of $\psi$.

Here i set 
\begin{align}
[\bar{Q}_{\dot{\alpha}}, A(x)]=0, \quad [Q_\alpha, A(x)] = - i\sqrt{2} \psi_\alpha(x)
\end{align}
The super jacobi identity gives
\begin{align}
&0=[\psi_\alpha, \{ Q_\beta, \bar{Q}_{\dot{\gamma}} \} ] + [ Q_\beta, \{\bar{Q}_{\dot{\gamma}}, \psi_\alpha \} ] + [ \bar{Q}_{\dot{\gamma}}, \{ \psi_\alpha, Q_\beta \}] \\
&=2i\sigma^\mu_{\phantom{\s}\beta\dot{\gamma}}\partial_\mu \psi_\alpha + i [ Q_\beta, X_{\alpha\dot{\gamma}} ] + i [ \bar{Q}_{\dot{\gamma}}, F_{\beta\alpha}] \\
&= 2i\sigma^\mu_{\phantom{\s}\beta\dot{\gamma}}\partial_\mu \psi_\alpha + \sqrt{2} \sigma^\mu_{\phantom{\m}\alpha\dot{\gamma}} [ Q_\beta, \partial_\mu A]  - i \sqrt{2} \epsilon_{\beta\alpha} [ \bar{Q}_{\dot{\gamma}},F] \\
&= 2i\sigma^\mu_{\phantom{\s}\beta\dot{\gamma}}\partial_\mu \psi_\alpha
 - i 2 \sigma^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\alpha\dot{\gamma}} \partial_\mu \psi_{\beta}
+ \sqrt{2} \epsilon_{\beta\alpha} \bar{\chi}_\gamma  
\end{align}

what i want to obatin is $\bar{\chi} = - \sqrt{2} \sigma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi$

I think something must be wrong in my computation. 
Could you correct my computation? Is my procedure right?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).